# Firebase compatibility errors

Tags: android, firebase

I have a problem that I always had, and tried to understand it, but never succesfully. The compatibility between firebase implementations. I take the repositories from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase , but it doesn't help me. I event put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of build.gradle, such in dependecies.

My implementations are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
```

It works very well without last one (storage) but I needed that, and when I put it there, i get some errors. If someone can explain why it works well with some versions, and with some not, I would apreciate that.

The error i get is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListenersCountChangedListener;
    at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source:3)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:66)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:53)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:155)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:642)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:358)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:321)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:305)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:53)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.0.0:47)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$IdTokenListenersCountChangedListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ainkiwi.taskme-gQJ3Y9hPNu2sUu1YIJxWBA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134).... and so on.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade the following dependencies into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
```

Check the list of dependencies here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions